# In kinetic theory of gases, in finding connection between pressure and molecular kin. energy, why $N/2$ & not $N/6$ molecules are assumed to hit wall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, thermal-conductivity

In my book While driving a relation between pressure and  average kinetic energy of a single molecule [i.e. $P = (Nmv^2)/2$ ], an ideal gas of $N$ molecules  is assumed to be enclosed in a cubical box of each face of area $A$.
Before starting calculations it is said that half of the total molecules $(N/2)$ will hit the right wall...
My doubt is why don't we assume that $N/6$ molecules will hit the right wall?

Comment: Because an infinitesimally small number of molecules have absolutely no velocity along the x-axis. Eventually, basically every molecule will hit every wall. And, at any moment in time, every molecule is has a component of velocity either towards or away from any given wall.

Comment: Because N/2 molecules has the respective velocity component pointing to the right. the other N/2 to the left.